# Flex extract dimension from .xlsx file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, xlsx

I try to read in a .xlsx File in a Flex Application.
Now I try to determine where are my information. Therefore I got the XML Data out of the .xlsx file:

```
var x:XML = <worksheet mc:Ignorable="x14ac"
  xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
  xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
     <dimension ref="A1:F77"/>
</worksheet>;
```

Now I like to get the dimensions attribute "ref". Therefore I use the following code:

```
var test:Object = x.dimension;
var value:Object = x.dimension.@ref;
```

Both work perfect if I leave the schema expression at the worksheet. How can I get the correct result with including schemas? Is there a nice way to get the XML without schemas?

Tanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because dimension is in the default namespace `xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"`

So you can simply get the default namespace of you xml and use it like this:

```
var ns:Namespace = x.namespace();
var value:Object=x.ns::dimension.@ref;
```

or create it youself and use it the same way:

```
var ns2:Namespace=new Namespace("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main");
var value2:Object=x.ns2::dimension.@ref;
```

Here the live test on wonderfl:
http://wonderfl.net/c/7XwU